# CFString isNaturallyRTL - message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dealloc, cfstring

I already googled for "CFString isNaturallyRTL" with 0 results.

these are my classes:

```
//in .H
@interface myViewController : UIViewController {
UITextField *from;
UITextField *to;
NSString *fromText;
NSString *toText;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* fromText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* toText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *from;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *to;

//in .m
@synthesize from, to;
@synthesize fromText, toText;

viewDidLoad(...) {
  fromText = @"Roma";
  toText   = @"Lecce";
}

- (void) drawRoute {
  if ( ([[from text] length] > 2) && ([[to text] length] > 2) ) 
 {
  fromText = from.text;
  toText = to.text;
    [...]
  }
}
```

Now, i have a view that open on button touch tha contains two text boxes and a button. Like this.

```
- (void) drawRouteTextboxes {
 from = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: [...] ];
 from.text = fromText;
 from.delegate = self;
 [ctr.view addSubview:from];
 [from release];

    to = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: [...] ];

    [...]

    [searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(drawRoute) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

It's all correct, compile and run.

First time that i click drawRouteTextboxes, it opens my view with default text setted ("Roma" and "lecce").
Second time, i open the view, edit textfield and call drawRoute. It's ok.
The third time that i call drawRouteTextboxes it return me this runtime error:

```
*** -[CFString _isNaturallyRTL]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3a8d140
```

I don't know where is the problem...
Someone know a solution?
It's the first time that i see this error!

thanks,
Alberto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's all correct, compile and run.

If it was all correct, it would run without error. ;)

This looks suspect:

fromText = from.text;
  toText = to.text;

If `from.text` and `to.text` are returning either autoreleased objects or objects that are later released, then the above doesn't retain the strings and could easily lead to an over-release problem as you are seeing.

Use `self.fromText = from.text;` instead.

Note that `NSString*` properties should almost *always* be `copy` and not `retain`.